# Ember.js image path

Tags: ember.js

In development paths of my assets (in particular images) are very different from the production (where I'll use a CDN).
I wrote an helper like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper("relative-path", function(filePath) {
    return App.get("assetsStartPath") +  filePath
});
```

This helper works fine, I only need to set "assetsStartPath" in App creation.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    assetsStartPath: "http://0.0.0.0:5000/my_static_path/",
    // in production will be for example "http://myapp.mycnd.com/foo/bar/img/"
    ...
});
```

And in my template

```
{{relative-path "img/some_image.png"}}
```

The problem is that I'd like to use this helper inside `bind-attr`, like this:

```
<imd {{bind-attr src="relative-path 'img/some_image.png'"}} />
```

Obviuosly this doesn't work.
How can I obtain the result I want?
Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you don't need two way binding for this, you can just use [unbound](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_unbound):

ie:

```
<img src="{{unbound relativePath}}img/some_image.png" />
```